# Limit notation where variable does not approach anything

Tags: probability, notation

I was reading an example in my probability textbook that states a limit as

$$\lim_{n}{P\left\{X \leq 3 - \frac{1}{n} \right\}}$$

where the RV $X=k$ is defined for $ k 
\in \mathbb{R}$

What exactly does the text book mean by $\lim_{n}$?

Comment: I'm sorry if this question is very basic or already answered, but I have never come across this before

Comment: The default interpretation is the limit as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Brian M. Scott provided the answer in a comment:

> The default interpretation is the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$